# FFT problems, is output correct?

Tags: c#, audio, fft, aforge

This code should take a .wav file, take the raw data into a byte array and convert it to a array of shorts, then to a complex. Then I take a small 5000 in length part of the complex number to feed through the FFT from AForge.Math. do these outcome complex numbers look correct? also if I thought that one would be freq and the other amp at the freq, am I incorrect here?

Here are a few examples of the output:

(-2.16700013595762, 0.68302023531242), (4.22590168063363, 4.0661547909796), (-5.01069934509754, -0.16041726303182), (-1.46395152700116, -6.23087698868018), (-2.96017908067037, 0.439816425795027),

Here is my code.

```
class Main
{

    WaveFileReader reader;
    short[] sample;
    Complex[] tmpComplexArray;

    public Main()
    {
        reader = new WaveFileReader("C:\\Users\\minford\\Downloads\\Adolf_Hitler_speeches_HD_English_Subtitles_.wav");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[reader.Length];
        reader.Read(buffer, 0 , buffer.Length);
        sample = new short[reader.Length];
        for (int n = 0; n < buffer.Length; n += 2)
        {
            sample[n] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, n);

        }


        //convert short to complex
       Complex[] complexData = new Complex[sample.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < complexData.Length; i++)
        {
            Complex tmp = new Complex(sample[i],0);

            complexData[i] = tmp;

        }



        //to get first 500 for testing.
        tmpComplexArray = new Complex[5000];
        int x = 0;

        for (int i =50000; i < 55000; i++)
        {
           Complex a = new Complex(complexData[i]);
           tmpComplexArray[x] = a;
           x++;
        }


        //run FFT
        FourierTransform.DFT(tmpComplexArray ,FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);



       //print out sample of conversion
        for (int i = 0; i < tmpComplexArray.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.Write(i+" :"+tmpComplexArray[i]+ ", ");
        }

        Console.Write("complete, ");
    }

}
```

edit :

I have created a sine wave and stored it in a short array, I pass this into a complex array then through the FFT. my problem I do not know what I am looking for in the result. Very new to DSP

a small part of the result is :
(0, 0), (2.21689333557151E-15, -7.34284855141709E-15), (-2.89901436190121E-15, -1.0077605416825E-14), (-6.53699316899292E-15, -5.64637225863862E-15), (-1.67688085639384E-14, -8.32711677389852E-15), (1.4495071809506E-14, 4.91429119620079E-15), (1.87014848052058E-14, 2.4891200212096E-15), (2.78532752417959E-15, -1.7036594357478E-14), (-7.33280103304423E-15, 8.1326056999842E-15), (-2.14868123293854E-14, -4.16955359128224E-15), (1.56319401867222E-14, 1.70135017185657E-14), (-1.00044417195022E-14, 3.97015753605956E-14), (-1.53477230924182E-15, -2.25943708187515E-14), (-2.36468622460961E-14, 8.33955127177433E-15), (4.03588273911737E-15, -3.4597213982579E-14), (-1.26192389870994E-14, -3.72946118432083E-15), (-1.9554136088118E-14, -2.36486386029355E-14), (-3.17754711431917E-14, 3.35198535594827E-15), (-1.48929757415317E-14, -5.97566440774244E-14), (3.50723894371185E-14, -3.57420759655724E-14), (1.65414348884951E-14, 4.11670697531008E-15), (-1.69393388205208E-14, 4.49968950988477E-14), (-2.01112015929539E-13, 9.97060212171164E-14), (2.32660113397287E-13, 1.59641189156901E-14)

Heres is my code:

```
        int sampleRate = 8000;
        short[] buffer = new short[8000];
        double amplitude = 0.25 * short.MaxValue;
        double frequency = 500;
        for (int n = 0; n < buffer.Length; n++)
        {
            buffer[n] = (short)(amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * n * frequency) /sampleRate));
        }

        Complex[] complexData = new Complex[buffer.Length];
          for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
         {
            Complex tmp = new Complex(buffer[i],0);

           complexData[i] = tmp;

          }



        FourierTransform.DFT(complexData ,FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);



       //print out sample of conversion
        for (int i = 0; i < complexData.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.Write(i+" :"+complexData[i]+ ", ");
        }

        Console.Write("complete, ");
```

Edit :

I am getting the spike in the correct bin. I see two, you mentioned because they are mirrored. Could you explain why this is happening?

Comment: True, my goal is analyzing famous speeches. I am starting for testing with 3 winston churchill, dwight D. Eisenhower and adolf hitler.

Comment: It is hard to tell if these values are what you should expect. The complex numbers contain information on how much a certain sine and with which phase is present in the audio track. To get the "amplitude" you'll need to take the modulus of the complex value.  The position in the array represents the frequency, but it depends on the sampling rate and other properties (can't remember directly). So, as Willeman stated, it might be best to check your results to a simple sine.

Comment: I have edited the question, now using a sine wave

Comment: It should have 2 spikes somewhere, the values you printed doesn't (E-15). The spikes should be somewhere in E-4 - E-0 range (guess). (2 spikes because the output is most likely mirrored)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a two issues:

1) You need to normalize your data to the -1.0 to 1.0 range. Otherwise the Aforge DFT algorithm will overflow.

```
Complex[] complexData = new Complex[buffer.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
{
    Complex tmp = new Complex(buffer[i]/(double)short.MaxValue, 0);
    complexData[i] = tmp;
}
```

2) You'll be able to see the peak easier if you look at the Magnitude of the complex numbers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < complexData.Length; i++)
{
     Console.Write(i+" :"+complexData[i].Magnitude+ ", ");
}
```

Since your DFT length is 8000 then each bin is 1Hz wide. Therefore the peak of your 500Hz sine wave would be in bin 500.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with the simplest case possible (sine-wave of frequency 'x') and verify that you get a spike at the frequency bin corresponding to x when taking the real values of the FFT output. If that works then you can start worrying about the phase information represented in the complex numbers.